# MySQL JOIN multiple results

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to select all of the roles a specific user has access to within a specific server. This is for a system that allows a user to manage one or more services. The amount of access a user has is assigned by whoever the service belongs to. Roles are grouped and that group is then what gets assigned to a user. A user may have more than one group.

This is the query that I made and expected to work, but it doesn't. I am guessing it doesn't work because the serverPermissions table can return more than 1 groupId based on what a user is assigned.

```
SELECT serverGroupRoles.roleId FROM `serverGroupRoles`, `serverPermissions`, `servers` 
    WHERE servers.identifier='someUniqueString' AND 
        serverPermissions.serverId=servers.id AND 
        serverPermissions.userId=1 AND 
        serverGroupRoles.groupId=serverPermissions.groupId
```

Here's a visual look of the tables, 'servers' table has other data, but it's unrelated.

servers table, identifier is a unique key:

```
id  |  identifier  |  ...
--------------------------
 1  |  someString  |  ...
 2  | someString02 |  ...
```

serverPermissions table:

```
serverId  |  groupId  |  userId
--------------------------------
    1     |     1     |     1
    1     |     2     |     1
    1     |     2     |     2
    2     |     3     |     1
    3     |     4     |     1
```

serverGroupRoles table:

```
groupId  |  roleId
------------------
   1     |    1
   1     |    2
   1     |    3
   2     |    1
   2     |    3
   3     |    4
   4     |    2
```

The roleId's are mapped in the application to a certain action.

This is what I am trying to accomplish, but with 1 query:
If you did something like,

```
SELECT id FROM `servers` WHERE identifier = 'someString'
```

Returns

```
id
--
 1
```

Then took the id that was returned from that,

```
SELECT groupId FROM `serverPermissions` WHERE serverId = 1 AND userId = 1
```

Then it would return

```
groupId
-------
   1
   2
```

Then with each groupId,

```
SELECT roleId FROM `serverGroupRoles` WHERE groupId = #
```

And the end result,

```
roleId
------
   1
   2
   3
```

Is there a good way to do this with 1 query?

Edit, query that accomplishes the task:

```
SELECT DISTINCT sgr.roleID
FROM serverPermissions sp
    INNER JOIN servers s ON s.id = sp.serverID
    INNER JOIN serverGroupRoles sgr ON sgr.groupID = sp.groupID
WHERE sp.userID = 1
    AND s.identifier = 'someString'
```

Comment: Can you provide the desired result set?

Comment: The desired result set would be the final block in the post that shows the row 'roleId'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's still a bit early here, but would this do what you want:

```
SELECT  DISTINCT sgr.roleID
FROM    serverPermissions sp
        INNER JOIN serverGroupRoles sgr ON sgr.groupID  = sp.groupID
WHERE   sp.serverID = 1
        AND sp.userID   = 1
```

I could be off the mark here as I'm not sure where the servers table comes into this.  If you're looking for data from that table you can join it in too:

```
SELECT  DISTINCT sgr.roleID, s.fieldName
FROM    serverPermissions sp
        INNER JOIN servers s            ON s.id = sp.serverID
        INNER JOIN serverGroupRoles sgr ON sgr.groupID  = sp.groupID
WHERE   sp.serverID = 1
        AND sp.userID   = 1
```

Comment: I accidentally left out a step in the breakdown. The application knows of a string unique to the server but not the id of the server.

Comment: Then would my second query work?  I'm assuming this is a field in the servers table?  If it's a field you need to pull then just replace my "s.fieldName" with the field's name.  If it's something you need to filter by, then remove that selected field, and add "s.fieldName=..." to the where clause.  If you give me more information I can update the query for you.

Comment: Last comment didn't seem to post for whatever reason. From your 2nd query, I took out s.fieldName and in the where clause, I modified sp.serverID to be sp.serverID=s.id and added s.identifier='someString' to the clause. The application has a 2 pieces of info to work with, the user's id and a unique string that can be used to identify a specific server. I need to be able to use the unique string (s.identifier) to get the server id to use for the other tables.

Comment: Anyways, your bottom one works with the changed where clause!

Comment: Sife, glad to hear it worked for you.  Could you please provide your updated query in a comment or as an addendum to your original post so others may benefit from it?  If you place it as a comment on this answer you should also use the checkbox to mark this as the answer so it appears at the top of the list.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
SELECT roleId
FROM `serverGroupRoles`
WHERE groupId in (SELECT groupId
                  FROM `serverPermissions`
                  WHERE serverId = 1 AND userId = 1 
                 )
```

Perhaps you actually want "SELECT distinct roleID" to eliminate duplicates.

You can extend this for servers, but I would do it as a set of joins:

```
SELECT distinct roleId
FROM `serverGroupRoles` sgr join
     `serverPermissions` sp
      on sgr.groupId = sp.groupId join
     `server` s
      on sp.serverid = s.id
WHERE s.identifier = 'someString' AND sgr.userId = 1
```

Comment: Sorry, I foolishly forgot a step. I need to select the server's id from the servers table because the application only knows of a string that is unique to each server rather than the server's id.